# GitHub Clone from VSCode eg-02-react-implicit-grant error /src/hoc/aux invalid argument

Tags: docusignapi

This question is regarding the repo for react implicit grant for docusign using react.

https://github.com/docusign/eg-02-react-implicit-grant

When I tried to clone the repo using VSCode, I received an error

> Git: fatal: cannot create directory at 'src/hoc/Aux': Invalid argument

When I looked into the repo, there is a file under src/hoc/aux/aux.js which has the text below.

> const aux = (props) => props.children;
>
> export default aux;

Is the file aux.js necessary? Because I was able to extract the zip files after skipping to extract aux.js.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to clone the https://github.com/docusign/eg-02-react-implicit-grant repo using the GitHub desktop and did not have any problems.

I suggest that you download the repo using git directly or use the download zip option from the repo's page.

### Re: aux.js

TL;DR. -- Yes, I believe the aux.js is needed.

Details: Unfortunately I'm not a React expert. (Even though I wrote this example.)

The /hoc directory is used for React Higher Order Components. In this case, I'm using it for a simple component that checks to see if the user has a valid token. I believe that the js file is needed. But you can find out by not including it as seeing what happens.

Also, note that I wrote this React example almost a year ago. You'll want to update it to current React best practices.

Answer (score -1):

Try renaming the aux folder and aux.js file inside it to any random name do it preferably in vscode it will let you know which name is allowed and which isn't, worked for me.